# iPhone how to send a large image along with a JSON file? Should I embed it within the JSON or send separately?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, uiimage

I'm trying to create a way to save the interface of my app in a JSON file. While static elements I can define by their frames and/or center points, the interface does **include a single image selected from the photo library.** Because some iPhones have 8MP cameras, I can anticipate that some images would be very large.

I would like to be able to **save this interface and send it over by email,** so another app user can re-open the file and see the same interface with the image included.

Currently I'm using JSONKit to save my data into a JSON object. This means that the email will contain a single JSON file containing both the layout parameters and the image. I've never worked with such large JSON files, so the question is - **will having several megs of image data within JSON present parsing issues?** Or should I select some other file container that would have : first part JSON file, second part raw image data and then separate that file into a JSON string and a raw data string?

This is what I'm using currently to get a JSON file. After adding NSData to JSON, the convert to json method returns nil

```
    NSString* currentURL = webView.request.mainDocumentURL.absoluteString;
    [dictionary setValue:currentURL forKey:@"webViewAddress"];

//this call correctly returns the json string
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary JSONString]);
    NSLog(@"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(arOverlayView.image);
//after this call, the json returns nil
    [dictionary setValue:imageData forKey:kimageData];
      NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary JSONString]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using email as a transport mechanism, your binary data will have to end up as something like Base64 encoded at some point in its life.  There is no "raw" format for email, there is only text.

At best you could implement [Base85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) encoding which is more efficient than Base64

So you are going to have to suck up the large file sizes unless you invent your own transport mechanism - such as a point to point TCP/IP based link.